# JPA references: are there any guarantees related to field contents?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

JPA's `EntityManager#getReference()` returns something very lazy that is usually a proxy. It only goes to the database when the properties are accessed. According to the documentation:

> Get an instance, whose state may be lazily fetched

What I want to know is whether it makes any sense to look into the fields of such a proxy.

I have the following two classes that form a one-to-many relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public UUID id;
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addChild(Child child) {
        children.add(child);
        child.parent = this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public UUID id;
    public String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    public Parent parent;
}
```

Please note that both classes use field access strategy (as `@Id` is on a field and not on a getter).

I add one `Parent` with two children to the database during test fixture setup via JDBC to avoid `Parent` instance caching in an `EntityManager`. I do not show this code as it is bulky and straightforward. If it is needed, I can add it later.

Then, I run the following tests:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testWithFind() {
    Parent parent = entityManager.find(Parent.class, parentId);

    assertThat(parent.name, is("Joe"));
    assertThat(parent.children, hasSize(2));
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void testWithGetReference() {
    Parent parent = entityManager.getReference(Parent.class, parentId);

    assertNull(parent.name);
    assertThat(parent.children, hasSize(0));

    assertThat(parent.getName(), is("Joe"));
    assertThat(parent.getChildren(), hasSize(2));

    // ... but still ...
    assertNull(parent.name);
    assertThat(parent.children, hasSize(0));
}
```

Both tests are successful.

I can see in the console that JPA actually queries the database. For `find()`-related test it is

```
Hibernate: select parent0_.id as id1_2_0_, parent0_.name as name2_2_0_ from parent parent0_ where parent0_.id=?
Hibernate: select children0_.parent_id as parent_i3_0_0_, children0_.id as id1_0_0_, children0_.id as id1_0_1_, children0_.name as name2_0_1_, children0_.parent_id as parent_i3_0_1_ from child children0_ where children0_.parent_id=?
```

For `getReference()` it is

```
Hibernate: select parent0_.id as id1_2_0_, parent0_.name as name2_2_0_ from parent parent0_ where parent0_.id=?
Hibernate: select children0_.parent_id as parent_i3_0_0_, children0_.id as id1_0_0_, children0_.id as id1_0_1_, children0_.name as name2_0_1_, children0_.parent_id as parent_i3_0_1_ from child children0_ where children0_.parent_id=?
```

As it can be seen, `find()` fills both `String` and a collection field ok. But for an 'entity' returned by `getReference()`, this is not true: the fields remain in their initial state even after the getters have been called.

I understand that it is impossible to intercept field access using proxy (or, probably, any other 'legal' mechanism), so the proxy primarily works at the level of getters. But the entities are annotated to use field access strategy, so it is clearly expected by the user that fields will be used to get the values, and not getters. I did not find any clarification in the specification, and it does not say anything about 'getter-only' semantics for such proxies (or I just did not find such mentions).

My questions are:

1. Is it a discrepancy of the JPA specification, or I just do not understand it correctly?
2. Can one use fields to access components of an entity returned by `getReference()`, or it makes no sense?

I'm using Hibernate 5.3.9 as a JPA provider.

Comment: Are the tests `assertThat(parent.getName(), is("Joe"));
    assertThat(parent.getChildren(), hasSize(2));` in your `testWithGetReference` successful? Is the SQL statement actually executed to fill the fields?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes, both tests succeed, and I can see the `SELECT`s Hibernate is making. I've updated the question with this information.

Comment: I believe, that the proxies fields can't change at all. Actually, I found [this article](https://xebia.com/blog/advanced-hibernate-proxy-pitfalls/) which explains your issue on point. See `Proxy Pitfall 1: Field Access`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer thank you, that's an interesting article. But it does not explain why the 'original' fields *must* remain the same forever (and I don't see any reason for that). Pure optimization 'this is a proxy, so no sane person will ever access its fields directly'?

Comment: That is how the proxy is implemented by hibernate. I'd say that is the explanation for your question. I'm afraid there is no other explanation

Comment: You're just not supposed to use public fields, ever. Encapsulation and polymorphism are key, and proxies rely on polymorphism. Fields are not polymorphic. Field-access is useful because it allows you to have properties without setters, and to distinguish between business logic access to the properties (which should always go through methods, and which could do more than just returning/setting the field), and pure population of the state of the entity by JPA.

Answer (score 2):

According to the JPA Specification it is not allowed to use public access to fields:

> 2.2 Persistent Fields and Properties
>
> The persistent state of an entity is accessed by the persistence
> provider runtime[1] either via JavaBeans style property accessors
> (“property access”) or via instance variables (“field access”).
> Whether persistent properties or persistent fields or a combination of
> the two is used for the provider’s access to a given class or entity
> hierarchy is determined as described in Section 2.3, “Access Type”.
>
> Terminology Note: The persistent fields and properties of an entity
> class are generically referred to in this document as the “attributes”
> of the class.
>
> The instance variables of a class must be private,
> protected, or package visibility independent of whether field access
> or property access is used. When property access is used, the property
> accessor methods must be public or protected.
>
> It is required that the
> entity class follow the method signature conventions for JavaBeans
> read/write properties (as defined by the JavaBeans Introspector class)
> for persistent properties when property access is used.
>
> In this case,
> for every persistent property property of type T of the entity, there
> is a getter method, getProperty, and setter method setProperty. For
> boolean properties, isProperty may be used as an alternative name for
> the getter method.